# Can I use jquery's ajax method instead of unirest for this API?

Tags: jquery, ajax

Here are the instructions for the API I'm trying to use. It recommends unirest but I can't install node on my server.

https://www.wordsapi.com/docs/?javascript#

this is the code I'm trying to use:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $.ajax({
        url: "https://wordsapiv1.p.mashape.com/words/soliloquy",
        type: "GET",
        datatype: "json",
        crossDomain: "true",
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        headers: {"X-Mashape-Key": "XXXXXXX"},
        success: function(result) {
            alert("SUCCESS!");
        },
        error: function(result) {
            alert("FAIL!");
        }
    });
});
```

but I'm getting a 401 unauthorized result for that request. The X-Mashape-Key header is included in the call with my api key, but it doesn't seem to want to accept it. Does unirest do something that this jquery ajax call doesn't?

Comment: can I see your server side code?

Comment: I don't have any. I'm trying to use jquery to access the API directly.

Answer (score 0):

Try with

```
beforeSend: function (xhr) {
   xhr.setRequestHeader ("Authorization", "Basic " + btoa(Your X-Mashape-Key));
},
```